# How can I invoke an approve() function call from the user and not the contract?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, contract-invocation, transferfrom

I am working on a basic staking platform for practice. I understand that the user of the platform has to call the `approve()` function and pass the contract into it in order for the contract to use the `transferFrom()`. However, as a beginner I don't know how to call that function from the perspective of the "user," in this case, my test accounts. How can I increase the allowance of a token that is already on the network?

Comment: Hi! We could use a bit more information - could you edit the question to include what framework or library you're using to connect to the blockchain you're using? (It might be useful to know what chain it is to, such as Hardhat Network, Ganache, or a testnet.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

As you stated, a contract can only transfer tokens from a user if the user has already approved the contract to spend the tokens. It is important to recognize that the user will call `approve()` on the *token contract* before interacting with your contract.

In practice, a dapp will usually ask a user to perform two transactions:

- `tokenContract.approve(yourContractAddress, amount);`
- `yourContract.yourFunction(); // This function has tokenContract.transferFrom()`

Comment: I understand this, but in a testing environment (without setting up a front end), how can I ask the user to perform these transactions? I could be wrong, but simply putting the approve() function in the contract and having the user call that doesn't work, does it?

Comment: I see. In a testing environment, you can import the ERC20 interface and attach an existing address to it. If you are using ethers.js, for example, you can use `erc20Token = ERC20Token.attach(erc20TokenAddress);` and then you can all `erc20Token.approve()`.

You can see more from the official docs [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory-attach).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with frontend js code:

```
        await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log("accounts: " + accounts)
        account = accounts[0];
        document.getElementById('wallet-address').textContent = account;    
        tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ERC20tokenABI, YOURTOKENCONTRACT_ADDRESS);
        tokenContract.methods.approve(yourContractAddress, amount).send({from: account},
                    function (err, res) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("An error occured", err);
                            return
                        }
                        console.log("Hash of the transaction: " + res)
                    }
                  )
```